# AppleScript - Can't get rid of delay after click

Tags: applescript, automation

I'm very new to scripting and using AppleScript. I'm on MacOS 10.14. I have been messing around with it making a few scripts to automate clicking Apple and 3rd-party menu bar items.

I have the following script written that clicks a certain menu bar item, presses the `down arrow` key and presses the `return` key.

The problem is, the click seems to be creating a 5-6 second delay before the key presses can fire. I searched for a solution but only found a couple posts talking about the issue. They both said the solution is to wrap the `click` command in `ignoring application responses` and `end ignoring` statements, however that doesn't seem to solve the problem for me.

I also looked up the delay command and tried specifying a delay of 1 second, but that didn't work either. It just adds another second of delay to the already-existing 5-6 second delay.

The code I've got is:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Enjoyable"
        click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2)
        key code 125
        key code 36
    end tell
end tell
```

With the `ignore` statements, I've written:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Enjoyable"
        ignoring application responses
            click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2)
        end ignoring
        key code 125
        key code 36
    end tell
end tell
```

With the `delay` statement, I've written:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Enjoyable"
        click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2)
        delay 1
        key code 125
        key code 36
    end tell
end tell
```

What other options could I try to get rid of the delay between the click and the key presses?

Comment: Are you doing this simply as an exercise in scripting? It seems a heavy-handed way of calling a menu item. If not, what precisely is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I originally made a few other scripts just addressing the menu items directly, which for this case would be like:

```tell application "System Events"
 tell process "Enjoyable"
  set enjoyableMenu to (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2)
  tell enjoyableMenu
   click
   tell (menu item 1 of enjoyableMenu)
    click
   end tell
  end tell
 end tell
end tell```

Sorry! Can't get the code to format correctly. But the point is, it wouldn't work this way despite working with 1st-party Apple menu bar items it worked with. So, I found this method and it works except the annoying delay.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. *What exactly are you trying to achieve?* At the moment you're asking about how to achieve what you think is the answer… which is what's known as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve automated toggling of the enable/disable toggle in the Enjoyable menu bar dropdown menu.

Comment: As I don't know what 'Enjoyable' is, I cant check how the menus work, but why not just use the Keyboard prefs & add a key command? No scripting required.

Comment: I tried that but those keyboard shortcuts in the Keyboad preferences only address app menus. They don't address menu bar items (apps on the right side of the menu bar). The script I have currently works; it just has a 5-6 second delay which I'm trying to get rid of.

So, I guess when you asked me what I'm trying to do, I should have said "I'm trying to remove the delay from the script I posted above."

Oh, and Enjoyable is a gamepad mapping app. https://yukkurigames.com/enjoyable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested three different ways, run in **Script Editor**, run as a standalone  **AppleScript** *application*, and run as an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* under **macOS Mojave** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```appleascipt
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        click menu bar item 1 of ¬
            menu bar 2 of ¬
            application process "Enjoyable"
end ignoring

delay 0.1
do shell script "killall 'System Events'"
delay 0.2

tell application "System Events"
    launch
    click menu item 1 of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu bar item 1 of ¬
        menu bar 2 of ¬
        application process "Enjoyable"
end tell
```

---

**Notes:**

Using **Accessibility Inspector**, a part of **Xcode**, it reveals there is no **action** assigned to `menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process "Enjoyable"` and is probably why it hangs with the original *code*, how you tried it.

To work around the 5 ~ 6 seconds delay using `ignoring application responses` I wrapped the first `tell application "System Events"` *command* with just a single task to perform, which allowed the *script* to proceed, and then killing the **System Events** *application process* allows the second `tell application "System Events"` *command* to perform its tasks with the minimal delay of ~1 second combined for the running of the whole *script*. This is of course much better than the 5 ~ 6 seconds delay without doing it in this manner.

The very small `delay` *commands* before and after the `do shell script "killall 'System Events'"` *command* are to allow time for the *menu bar item* to show its *menu* and for **System Events** to terminate before calling it again to click the target *menu item*. The *value* of the `delay` *command* may need to be slightly adjusted and if so do as necessary.

As previously mentioned, this worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>, however, if for some reason the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, does not work for you, then here is a programatic way to click the target *menu bar item* on the **menu bar** using either the [**`cliclick`**](https://www.bluem.net/en) or [**`MouseTools`**](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html) *third-party utility*.

- I have `cliclick` and `MouseTools` located in `/usr/local/bin/`, so change it in the *code* if you have them located elsewhere.

---

### Using: cliclick

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```appleascipt
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set thePositionSizeList to ¬
        the {position, size} of ¬
            menu bar item 1 of ¬
            menu bar 2 of ¬
            application process "Enjoyable"

set xPos to ¬
    (item 1 of item 1 of thePositionSizeList) + ¬
    (item 1 of item 2 of thePositionSizeList) / 2 ¬
    as integer

set yPos to ¬
    (item 2 of item 1 of thePositionSizeList) + ¬
    (item 2 of item 2 of thePositionSizeList) / 2 ¬
    as integer

set shellCMD to {¬
    "/usr/local/bin/cliclick -r c:", ¬
    xPos, ",", yPos, " w:50 c:", ¬
    xPos, ",", (yPos + 22)} as string

do shell script shellCMD
```

**Notes:**

With `cliclick` one can string multiple *events* together and why the code ends at the `do shell script shellCMD` *command* as it clicks both the *menu bar item* and the *menu item*, especially since it's the first *menu item* being targeted.

[**`cliclick`**](https://www.bluem.net/en) is available as a *precompiled binary executable*, source *code*, and also can be installed using **Homebrew**.

The current *precompiled binary executable* release of `cliclick` (5.0) will not run on **macOS Mojave** and I used an older version I already had (Version 4.0.1, released 2018-04-10). If you cannot acquire an earlier version you can use `MouseTools` instead.

---

### Using: MouseTools

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```appleascipt
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set thePositionSizeList to ¬
        the {position, size} of ¬
            menu bar item 1 of ¬
            menu bar 2 of ¬
            application process "Enjoyable"

set xPos to ¬
    (item 1 of item 1 of thePositionSizeList) + ¬
    (item 1 of item 2 of thePositionSizeList) / 2 ¬
    as integer

set yPos to ¬
    (item 2 of item 1 of thePositionSizeList) + ¬
    (item 2 of item 2 of thePositionSizeList) / 2 ¬
    as integer

set shellCMD to {¬
    "/usr/local/bin/MouseTools -x ", ¬
    xPos, " -y ", yPos, " -leftClick"} as string

do shell script shellCMD

delay 0.2

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click menu item 1 of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu bar item 1 of ¬
        menu bar 2 of ¬
        application process "Enjoyable"
```

---

**Notes:**

With `MouseTools` one can only perform one *event* at a time and why after clicking the *menu bar item* on the **menu bar** I just switched back to using **System Events** to click the target *menu item*, vs. calling `MouseTools` a second time, either within the first `do shell script` *command* or a second `do shell script` *command* possibly after a short delay.

For example, you could change the `shellCMD` to:

```applescript
set shellCMD to {¬
    "/usr/local/bin/MouseTools -x ", ¬
    xPos, " -y ", yPos, " -leftClick;", ¬
    "/usr/local/bin/MouseTools -x ", ¬
    xPos, " -y ", (yPos + 22), " -leftClick"} as string
```

Then remove everything after the `do shell script` *command*.

[**`MouseTools`**](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html) is available as a *precompiled binary executable* and source *code*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Not only did you offer a working solution, you offered several working solutions.  Good job dude +1

Comment: Wow! What an excellent and thorough answer. Thank you so much and I sincerely apologize that it took me almost a month to respond. I got the code working with the first example. Now I'm trying to get that code to run at login. I tried putting the .scpt file in my login items, but it won't run. I tried minute of delay before the code to give everything time to load. I also tried making an Automator app and putting that in my login items, but that didn't work either, even with a confirmation pop up before running. Oh well! I might make another post about it. Thanks again so much for your help!

Comment: @SwineBurglar, RE: "Now I'm trying to get that code to run at login. I tried putting the .scpt file in my login items, but it won't run." --  Putting a **.scpt** _file_  in the **Login Items** is not the way to go as it just opens the _script_ up in **Script Editor**. You need to use an _executable_, i.e., an _application_.  That said, because you never mentioned running this as a **Login Items**, then yes, it belongs the topic of another question. I will of course respond to it with what else will be necessary to accomplish the goal.

Comment: @user3439894 I was writing a new question but then I figured it out! I thought more about what you said, opened the Script Editor and found Export>Application and created an app, gave it the system permissions and put it in my login items. I also added key "LSUIElement" and value "true" in the Info.plist in the app to hide it from the app switcher during the delay. I now have it running at start up with no issues. Thank you again so much for your help! Should I make a post to answer that question still or is it too basic to bother with? I couldn't find the info when I searched, so maybe yes?

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, although it only applies to people using the Bartender application (https://www.macbartender.com).

Bartender itself has support for some basic AppleScript commands and one of those commands is the `activate` command:

```
activate v : Will Show and Activate a menu bar item, you must provide menu item ID, these can be found via the list menu bar items command
  activate MIID text : The menu bar item ID to activate
    [with text]
```

The `activate` command is the equivalent of the `click` action from `System Events`.

To obtain the ID of the item that you wish to activate you use the `list menu bar items` command:

```
list menu bar items v : List current menu bar item IDs, so you know what to use for the activate and show commands
  list menu bar items
    → text : the IDs of the menu bar items
```

The ID doesn't seem to change, so all you need to do is obtain the ID manually once and then simply use it in your AppleScript like so:

```
tell application "Bartender 4"
    activate "org.openvpn.client.app-Item-1"
end tell

-- now you can click on any menu item

tell application "System Events" to tell process "OpenVPN Connect" to tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2    
    try
        click menu item "Disconnect" of menu 1

(... script cut off)
```

I my case I was scripting the OpenVPN Connect application (https://openvpn.net/vpn-client/).

I hope this information helps someone who uses the Bartender application but didn't think to go through the Bartender API.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much for posting this. I've had Bartender for years and never knew it could do this. I will give it a try when I have a chance and see what I can do. How did you learn about this functionality? I just checked the Bartender official site but couldn't find any documentation about anything like that.

Comment: If you scroll enough on the main page you can see it mentioned alongside other features, but there is no information regarding the actual usage of their AppleScript library. According to [this page](https://www.macbartender.com/Bartender4/release_notes/) the functionality has been added in version 4.0.41, which is fairly new (about 1 year ago). I simply wondered if I could interact with the Bartender app directly and so I navigated to the app’s AppleScript dictionary using the Script Editor and there it was.

Comment: Wow! This is totally embarrassing, but I've been piecing together my Mac scripting knowledge as I go, and I didn't realize there were dictionaries for 3rd party apps. I had been using the dictionary for the Apple apps/services by clicking "Window>Library", but that only shows the 1st party dictionaries. I just noticed the "File>Open Dictionary..." item now. I checked and Bartender 3 also has a dictionary. I am still on MacOS 10.14, and Bartender 4 is for MacOS 11+, but that's great to see there's a dictionary for Bartender! Thanks again for your help!